# how to change spatie tag slug generator method

Tags: laravel, slug

I use this package https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable to generate slug for my models. Also, I use spatie tag to manage tags. the problem is that the spatie tag uses its own logic to generate a slug. How can I force the spatie tag package to use eloquent-sluggable instead of its own slug?
The spatie tag package has a config file like this.

```
    <?php
return [
    /*
     * The given function generates a URL friendly "slug" from the tag name property before saving it.
     * Defaults to Str::slug (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-slug)
     */
    'slugger' => null,
];
```

what should I write in front of 'slugger' to use eloquent-sluggable instead of Str::slug

Comment: It's pretty obvious if you look at their code: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-tags/blob/master/src/HasSlug.php#L21

Comment: I saw it before. The code says that use slugger method in the config file or if it is null use Str::slug. the question is that what should I write in front of 'slugger'?

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the target method as a string.

For example:

```
'slugger' => 'Illuminate\Support\Str::slugify'
```